# Why does my title image disappear? 

Tags: android, android-layout

The Title ImageView is gone when the pbar is visible, and then appears when its layout is set to gone...I don't understand why the ImageView is not displaying??

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/title_pbar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/title_s"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_pbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ImageView` is set relative to the `ProgressBar`, so no `ProgressBar`, no `ImageView`. Try a different view layout. And if you can't change from RelativeLayout (for whatever reason), set the `ImageView` relative to a stationary view.